# World Wide Web Services rule doesn't exist

Tags: ios, debugging, windows-firewall, safari-web-inspector, telerik-appbuilder

I'm trying to use the Web Inspector in Telerik AppBuilder Windows client to debug a website on iOS. However, when I open the Inspector, none of the styling rules show up on the right side. I tried following the first step in this link:

http://blog.falafel.com/ios-web-inspector-on-windows-with-telerik-appbuilder/

However, **there is no predefined WWW Services (HTTP-In) rule in my list of Inbound Rules**. Has anyone else had this problem? Do I have to create one?

Comment: Have you tried the rest of the tutorial without the firewall rule? It should work fine as-is.

Comment: Yeah I did, and the styling won't show up. So I thought it must be because of the first step.

Comment: Can you inspect elements using the dev tools though?